# Adding string fields to the table in update

Tags: php, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter how to add string to fields?

```
$this->db->where('acctg_store_id',$data['acc_store_id']);
    $this->db->set('dscr',dscr . $data['desc']);
    $this->db->set('stat',$data['val_selected']);
    $this->db->update('acctg_store',$db)

$this->db->where('acctg_store_id',$data['acc_store_id']);
```

`dscr` is in text and in update, I want to add string to `dscr`

Comment: `$this->db->set('dscr',  "something here " . $data['desc']);`

Comment: $this->db->set('dscr',dscr . $data['desc']);   : dscr in the table

Comment: what is  `dscr` ?? you cannot use like `dscr . $data['desc']` because dscr not seems to be a valid variable. it can be `$dscr` or else it can be a constant..? can you please explain what do you really want to achieve.

Comment: dscr is the column in the acctg_store table .for example dscr is 'abc' and in update dscr become 'abc/ddd'

Comment: does it means `abc` is the old value in `descr before updation`   and  new value is `ddd` and after updation it will become  `abc/ddd`

Comment: ok  whates the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to update the field `dscr` by appending the new value with old value of `dscr`. So you can get the current value in `dscr`

```
$this->db->where('acctg_store_id',$data['acc_store_id']);
$res = $this->db->get("acctg_store");
$row = $res->row();
$dscr = $row->dscr;
```

then append this value `$dscr` in updation

```
$this->db->where('acctg_store_id',$data['acc_store_id']);
$this->db->set('dscr', $dscr . "/". $data['desc']);
$this->db->set('stat',$data['val_selected']);
$this->db->update('acctg_store',$db)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
$data = array(
        'dscr' => $data['desc'],
        'stat' => $data['val_selected'],
);

$this->db->where('acctg_store_id', $data['acc_store_id']);
$this->db->update('acctg_store', $data);
```

[Updating Data](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->db->where('acctg_store_id',$data['acc_store_id']);
$dscr="dscr" . $data['desc'];
$this->db->set('dscr',$dscr);
$this->db->set('stat',$data['val_selected']);
$this->db->update('acctg_store',$db);
```